# How can I move the mouse with just a physical keyboard?

Tags: windows, mouse

I'm looking for software that allows me to move the mouse (and click, of course) on Windows with just my physical keyboard. Essentially, something like [mouseless](https://github.com/jbensmann/mouseless) or [xmouseless](https://github.com/jbensmann/xmouseless) but for Windows. Ideally it would have a featureset similar to mouseless, i.e.:

> When starting xmouseless, it grabs the keyboard and all defined bindings are available. When pressing an exit key, the program exits.
>
> The usage is quite intuitive and with some practice, you can move the pointer to a specific location very fast. Basically, you move the pointer by pressing some keys (the defaults are i, k, j and l for up, down, left and right) and change the speed by pressing modifier keys. The keys f, d and s (by default) are used to simulate mouse clicks and grabbing. With some other keys, you can scroll up, down, left and right and execute previously defined shell commands.
>
> You probably want to define a key binding to start xmouseless.

Answer (score 2):

## Microsoft Windows

Go to the "ease of access" settings in the control panel. Scroll down to the "interaction" section and choose "mouse". Turn on  "use the numeric keypad to move the mouse pointer".

You can now move the mouse with the number pad (arrows: <kbd>4</kbd>,<kbd>8</kbd>,<kbd>6</kbd>,<kbd>2</kbd>) and click (<kbd>5</kbd>).

[image: Screenshot of keyboard mouse settings]

Comment: Thanks. It's not especially easy to move a mouse with mouse keys, but it works.